# "Argument error" in Python using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to fetch data from database using sqlalchemy in but i get the following error

> sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Column expression, FROM clause, or other columns clause element expected, got [Table('params', MetaData(), Column('paramID', Integer(), table=, primary_key=True, nullable=False), Column('item', String(), table=), Column('value', Float(), table=), schema=None)]. Did you mean to say select(Table('params', MetaData(), Column('paramID', Integer(), table=, primary_key=True, nullable=False), Column('item', String(), table=), Column('value', Float(), table=), schema=None))?

Code:

```
metadata = MetaData()
    params = Table('params', metadata,
       Column('paramID', Integer(), primary_key=True),
       Column('item', String),
       Column('value', Float),
       Column('buttongroup', String),
       Column('fg_color', String),
       Column('bg_color', String))
                          
            engine = create_engine('...')
            con = engine.connect()
            selpar = select([params]).order_by(params.c.paramID)
            rppar = con.execute(selpar).fetchall()
```

Why is this happening? Is it an error with the database table or with the python script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of SQLAlchemy 2.0, select [no longer accepts a list as an argument](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/migration_20.html#select-no-longer-accepts-varied-constructor-arguments-columns-are-passed-positionally).  Provide individual positional arguments instead:

```py
select(params).order_by(params.c.paramID)

select(params.c.item, params.c.value)

select(some_table, some_other_table)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this way as well.

```
select(params).order_by(params.columns[paramID])

select(params.columns[item], params.columns[value])

select(some_table, some_other_table)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).